# Issue with Weather Underground API-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I just finished a simple weather web app using the Weather underground API and the Gem wunderground. I got the site up, through Heroku, and it can be found here: 
https://mike-weather.herokuapp.com/ . When I was building the app, it worked perfectly but when I put it up on the web, it appears that when I enter a city and select a state it does nothing. Does anyone know what is wrong or how to fix this? The code for my project is at github, username ravenusmc. Thank you for any help that may be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest double checking to make sure you have ENV['wunderground_api_key'] set on heroku.

You can check the environment variables by running 'heroku config'.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I completely forgot about that!